# How to use medeadown as alternative for leveldown in PouchDB

Tags: node.js, pouchdb, leveldown

I am working on node express API project which uses PouchDB and it should sync with remote CouchDB. Its working fine in the desktop.
I am not able to use PouchDB in Android/iOS. The reason is that leveldown which came as a dependency of PouchDB, is not able to compile in Android/iOS.
From this perspective, I have 2 choices:

1. I should get a way to compile leveldown in mobile.
2. Or I should find how to use some other alternative for leveldown in pouch db (eg:medeadown, as PouchDB folks suggest)

Comment: So what is your question? What problem do you need help solving?

Comment: @Flimzy  As I said, its worrking fine in desktop. But its not wworking in android/ios
While we run in android, I am getting an error:
"Cannot locate symbol napi_get_global referenced by /data/data/myproject/apibuild/api/node_modules/leveldown/prebuilds/android-arm64/node.napi.amv8.node"
Is there any way to compile it in ios and android?

Comment: If its not possible, Can we use medeadown instead of leveldown? According to the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pouchdb/xEdGxX7JIiM, we can do it. How can we implement in pouchdb module?